# CAShapeLayer clipped by image view clip to bounds

Tags: ios, uiimageview, cashapelayer

I am trying to customize UIImage view to include a red/green circle to show online status. My current code is like so:

```
import UIKit

class AvatarImageView: UIImageView {

    enum AvatarImageViewOnlineStatus {
        case online
        case offline
        case hidden
    }

    var onlineStatus: AvatarImageViewOnlineStatus = .hidden

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setup()
    }

    private func setup() {
        clipsToBounds = true
        layer.cornerRadius = frame.size.width / 2.0
        let circleShapeLayer: CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        circleShapeLayer.path = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 30, height: 30)).cgPath
        circleShapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        layer.addSublayer(circleShapeLayer)
    }

}
```

However the layer is also clipped:

[image]

`maskToBounds` on the layer is by default set to `false` the docs state:

> A Boolean indicating whether sublayers are clipped to the layer’s bounds. Animatable.

However it is still clipped. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `clipsToBounds = true` is probably overriding it - Maybe better to use a composite view

Comment: @MadProgrammer tried the same adding a uIview instead of a layer and get the same result

Comment: Don't add the `UIView` to the image view, simply position it over the top within the same container (so you might need to start with a simple `UIView` and add each to it instead)